# How is the current function converting an object to an array in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I got this code from the internet. I don't know how the

```
$databases = current($res->toArray());
```

is working in the code. I am new in MongoDB and PHP. How is the `current` function able to retrieve all values? What exactly is `executeCommand` retrieving?

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$listdatabases = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listDatabases" => 1]);
$res = $mng->executeCommand("admin", $listdatabases);


$databases = current($res->toArray());

foreach ($databases->databases as $el) {

    echo $el->name . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$res = $mng->executeCommand("admin", $listdatabases);` executes the `listDatabases` [command](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-command.php) and assigns the result to `$res`. The result is a [Cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) object, which has a [`toArray`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) method.

The result of some `$res->toArray()` is, not surprisingly, an array. Its first element is an object that contains the list of databases.

Now, [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) is not a function specific to MongoDB. It's a standard PHP function that returns the current element of an array. Since the array was just created, the current element is the first element, the object that contains the list of databases.

So `$databases = current($res->toArray());` gets you an object (`$databases`) that has a property `databases` which contains an array of database objects that you can iterate with `foreach`.

Comment: can we get same result using foreach on executeCommand() object ?